# GraphicsMagick for iPhone development

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, graphicsmagick

I want to use image manipulation functionality from GraphicsMagick for my iPhone app, but I'm finding it quite hard to locate good instructions to set up the library, and sample code for how to use it in Objective-C. Do such instructions or code exist?

Answer (score 1):

Try the this tool for compilation: 
http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=graphicsmagick-tools&max_rows=25&style=nested&viewmonth=201109

For me GraphicsMagick is performing far better than ImageMagick.

Comment: if you already done this, can you provide how to use it? I got the script but I'm a bit confused to use this script (i.e. GraphicsMagick-1.4 ???)

Comment: Script usage is pretty easy and it is telling whats needed everytime you start it. If you need more help - skype me: moushkov

Comment: Is there any graphicmagick library for iOS?. As @REALFREE said.. the script now is a bit confused..

Comment: @zainoz.zaini I haven't try but you can try either https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage for objc or https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage2 for swift.

Answer (score -1):

GraphicsMagick is it available for iOS or Mac Os X? You can try Some Apple's sample like GLImageProcessing and some sample source on github and google svn for objective-c image processing.

Comment: Not an answer... better served as a comment.